# How to apply an impulse to an object WITHOUT box2d libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, physics, gravity

I have a game that is almost done but I forgot about gravity and impulse, i did not want to implement box2d and i got the gravity to work, but can some body explain how to apply an impulse without box2d?

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate an impulse just by adding a velocity to the objects velocity. Like that:

```
class GameObject {
    private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();

    public void applyImpulse(Vector2 impulse) {
        velocity.add(impulse);
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        float dampingPerSecond = 0.5f;
        float dampingFactor = Math.max(0f, 1 - deltaTime*dampingPerSecond);
        velocity.scl(dampingFactor);
    }
}
```

Now you might use it like this: `object.applyImpulse(new Vector2(3, 2));`. In case you update all your `GameObject`s in every frame, your object will slow down after an impulse was given. Which is what you would expect to happen, if no further impulses hit your object. Doing this in a realistic way though is difficult and might only be achieved by using box2d. You might however tweak that and hope that it will work in your game. Remember to always apply your gravity after  that though.

Comment: Every frame. That's why it takes the deltaTime.